# Is there any way of using apex:actionRegion without ruining my design?

Tags: visualforce, actionsupport, formatting

I'm trying to use rerender on a form. Quite simple in fact, besides the problem I've been unable to solve.

Whenever I use apex:actionRegion, my form structure is ruined (for example, the fields align on the left while the rest is centered) and using immediate="true" on a selectList change event won't rerender the target.

Is there anyway to rerender required fields without destroying the form design?

Best regards.

Comment: Can you add some code? It will help to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry for not having any code in the post, my question was answered with what I needed by JimRae, thank you anyway for the attention given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use an ActionRegion, you need to restructure your page, using a pageBlockSectionItem

You'll need something like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Data Section" collapsible="false">
   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.myobject__c.fields.Tester__c.label}" for="testerField"/>
      <apex:actionRegion >
         <apex:inputField value="{!myobject__c.Tester__c}" required="true" id="testerField">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock" />
         </apex:inputField>
      </apex:actionRegion>
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
           <!-- ..........More Fields........ -->
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Sorry for only answering now. My pageblock has two columns defined in the pageblock, this solution works but drags my form to the left.

Comment: Nevermind, I've got it working! Thank you very much.